# PHP - auto detect (raw)urlencode

Tags: php, urlencode, urldecode

A PHP file is receiving a URL encoded string via GET. However, some scripts may send strings encoded with the `urlencode()` function, while other scripts may send strings encoded with the `rawurlencode()` function.

What would be the best way to check which function was used to encode the string, so the appropriate decoding function (`urldecode()` or `rawurldecode()`) can be called?

So far, my only idea is code like this:

```
if (stristr($string, "%20"))...
```

Comment: THis is something you should state in the documentation of your api, what remote urlencoding the other end should use

Comment: Alright, so how does it answer my question?

Comment: `echo this_sign_is_on_url('+') === true ? 'urldecode' : 'rawurldecode';` Don't know....

Comment: It answers your question by telling you to implement a protocol and not accept every garbage someone sends you. Imagine if TCP/IP protocol tried to be smart and guess what the other side meant, instead of implementing a protocol to work by. If you receive malformed request or something you can't work with, have your script return an error message and hang up.

Comment: I know what should or should not be done, but the fact is that the script wasn't developed by me, I "overtook" it and now want to change from urlencode to rawurlencode while maintaining compatibility with old installations. So I need an answer THIS QUESTION ONLY.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two functions take any character defined by the regular expression `[^0-9A-Za-z_~-]` and convert it to a percent sign followed by its hexadecimal codepoint. The only difference between the two encoding methods is `rawurlencode()` uses a `%20` for a space, instead of the `+` used by `urlencode()`.

For decoding, this means that *any* sequence that matches the regular expression `%[0-9A-F]{2}` will be properly decoded by *either* function. That only leaves a `+` to worry about, which will not get decoded properly by `rawurldecode()`. So, you can use `urldecode()` on the server side and not worry about any testing.

```
<?php
$str = "foo bar baz";
$raw = rawurlencode($str);
$enc = urlencode($str);

echo rawurldecode($raw);
echo rawurldecode($enc);
echo urldecode($raw);
echo urldecode($enc);
?>
```

Output:

```
foo bar baz
foo+bar+baz
foo bar baz
foo bar baz
```

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to read the actual question and post an working example.